# How do I group these results using Levenshtein distance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

At the moment I am getting looping through a list twice (for-loop inside a for-loop) and using Levenshtein distance to comparing the different entries in the list to see if they have a specific property (`tag`) to group them in an array together using the following:

```js
for (const [key1, value1] of players.entries()) {
  for (const [key2, value2] of players.entries()) {
    key1.forEach((keya) => {
      key2.forEach((keyb) => {
        const nameSimilarity = similarity(keya, keyb) // returns value between '0' and '1'
        const tag = keya.replace(tagDecoRegex, '').toLowerCase()
        if (value1 !== value2 && nameSimilarity >= 0.7) {
          if (!set[tag]) {
            set[tag] = [value1]
            if (!set[tag].includes(value2)) set[tag].push(value2)
          }
          else if (!set[tag].includes(value1)) set[tag].push(value1)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Now this works fine but I am trying to group them based on `nameSimilarity`, not the `tag` they have in common, although I do want the `tag` to be the object's `key`

I am looking for improvement because of results like this:

```js
{
  beamed: [ 'Seth#Beamed', 'John #Beamer', 'Alex#BEAMED' ],
  beamer: [ 'John #Beamer', 'Seth#Beamed' ],
}
```

It should instead be:

```js
{
  beamed: [ 'Seth#Beamed', 'John #Beamer', 'Alex#BEAMED' ],
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a full [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE, but even with one it doesn't sound like the operation you're describing is well defined. "Similarity" (`~`) isn't a transitive relation: so you could have `A~B`, `B~C` and `C~D` but *not* `A~D`.  Do `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` all belong in the same bucket at the end?  If not, how do you decide where to divide them?

Comment: I am tokenising the strings and checking for similarities using the tags, `#Beamed` in this case, then if the similarity is over 70% (or 0.7) it will create an object array with the tag as the key and the usernames as the values. This isn't working well as sometimes there are tags that are very similar to each other, `#Beamer` & `#Beamed` that end up in different array lists since it checks if a key that matches the tags exists and creates that object array accordingly instead of using the 0-1 value from `nameSimilarity` to group them into 1 object array

Comment: what is the initial data set? Can you add that as well.

Comment: That isn't relevant, I only added the explanation above for context, I am trying to focus on what happens within the second `forEach` loop

Comment: The data set and anything else that makes this into a reproducible example is relevant to the extent that we can play around with it and try things.  Otherwise you will get suggestions from people who can't test whether their answer works.  ... I'm still not sure what it means to group by "similarity of over 70%".  To group things you need an equivalence relation, but "similarity of over 70%" is not one.  Imagine you have tags like "beamed" "beamer" "beater" "better" "butter" "buster" "bustee" "bustle" "bastle" "castle".  What groups do you make there?